# How to get full path to user's type="file" using jQuery Fileupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, jquery-file-upload

Im trying to build file preview feature before file being uploaded to the server.

Im stucked with the problem of reading file from the user's computer, not a server

Im usuing [jquery Fileupload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) which fires the file processing on the change function

```
  return $('#new_order_file').fileupload({
    change: function(e, data) {
        return $.each(data.files, function(index, file) {
            read_file(file);
            console.log(file)
        });
    },
  });
```

Log gives File - name, size, type, *proto* and LastmodifiedDate

Than, this part is tricky for me, I know that I have to use `FileReader()` but Im not sure how to

```
function read_file(f){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#CO-show-model').css('display', 'block');
        loaded(f.name, e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
}
```

Next, loaded function is for displaying the file model using three.js

```
function loaded(file) {
    var uploaded_file = file // gives 404
    // var uploaded_file = './stl/test-file.stl' // ASCII test
}
```

The fucntion itself is good, I tested it with an hardcoded path to some test file. But the problem is that it was on a server. Now, script gives an 404 for http://example.com/filename.stl which is true, because I pass `file.name` there. If I just pass `file`, it gives 404 for http://example.com/[object%20File]

**Edit 1:**
I tried suggest ReadAsDataUrl, but seems to be that it's not supported by three.js. Also, the FileReader() seems to be ok

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get the data of uploaded file in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505333/get-the-data-of-uploaded-file-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Your `file` is an object so you have to get the right attribute from it.
Take a look here [Filereader Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

Comment: If I change reader to readAsDataURL(f) - I got an error from three.js for XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 ((

Answer (score 1):

It's a security feature. Browsers will not give you the actual local url to the file you are uploading.

See [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

Edit: Maybe what you are looking for is this question instead? [What is the preferred method for loading STL files in Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060261/what-is-the-preferred-method-for-loading-stl-files-in-three-js)

Comment: That explain a lot. However, some website have this feature. I was actually trying to adopt source code from http://www.viewstl.com and their FileReader seems to be ok :(

Comment: I think your question is wrong then. Are you asking how to read the data of a file in Javascript or how to get the full path to a file? viewstl.com are simply showing the filename, which you do have access to.