# How can import and display 3D files (.stl) in a Web App using JAVA?

Tags: java, web, flash, 3d

I want to write a Web App using Java that behaves like an **STL View-er**. Just import the file from disk and the app shows you the 3D content . Is this hard to do? I'm having trouble finding resources. I don't know where to start. Has anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with 3D but a quick search showed that it's possible to use STL files in JavaScript and since it's a webapp you're gonna want to be using that anyway, you can use HTML5 File Input to ask the user to provide the file, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51785570/7770787)'s the link.
By the way it uses three.js which is a library I'm also not familiar with but in the post I linked there's an example of how to use it.